# Cannot stop processing request in JSF phase listener

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

In phase listener I can not stop processing. jsf does not care my responseComplete call. How  can I stop processing in phase listener?

```
@Override
public PhaseId getPhaseId() {return PhaseId.RESTORE_VIEW;}

@Override
public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {}

@Override
public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    UIViewRoot viewRoot = fc.getViewRoot();
    if (checkweirdcase()) {
        LOGGER.debug("ViewId " + viewRoot.getViewId());
    } else {
        event.getFacesContext().responseComplete();
    }
    LOGGER.debug(event.getPhaseId());
}
```

Comment: When will `checkweirdcase` method return `true`?

Comment: What's the purpose of *stop processing in phase listener*?